# Migrating from Fabric to firebase Crashlytics

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

i am migrating from Fabric to Firebase crashlytics in my android project, I have changed all the gradle files accordingly as per https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=android#java

But in my Analytics file i have import which I want to convert to `FirebaseAnalytics`

```
import com.crashlytics.android.answers.Answers;
import com.crashlytics.android.answers.CustomEvent;
```

I have changed the import to

```
import com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics;
```

but not sure how can I use to this code

```
private static void logCrashlyticsEvent(String event, Map<String, String> map, App app, Settings settings, DeviceTools deviceTools, boolean addGenericData) {
    CustomEvent analyticEvent = new CustomEvent(event); // Custom event needs changing


    if (map != null){
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry: map.entrySet()){
            analyticEvent.putCustomAttribute(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
    }

    Answers.getInstance().logCustom(analyticEvent); // Answers needs changing
}
```

please suggest how to fix this

Thanks a ton in advcance

Rao

Answer (score 0):

According to the Fabric to Firebase Crashlytics [migration guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?platform=android#can_only_use_data_collected_by):

> You can no longer collect data with Fabric Answers after upgrading to the Firebase Crashlytics SDK. To get metrics for crash-free users and breadcrumbs, switch over to using Google Analytics instead. Note that your historical Answers data cannot migrate to Firebase.

> Visit [Start using Google Analytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/start-using-analytics?platform=android) to learn how to add Google Analytics to your app.